# C# string representation of bytes 128-255

Tags: .net, serial-port

I am working on re-constructing/improving a formerly developed C#/.NET project.
The serial communicator is not able to convert bytes 128-255 into specialized strings. I tried applying Unicode encoding based on characters seen in the working version of this project. With encoding applied, the "Message failed to send exception" is being thrown. Any pointers on solving/probing further into this problem are much appreciated.
Thanks.

```
    public virtual string WriteData(string s, int expectedResponseLength)
    {

        lock (messageLock)
        {
            resetEvent.Reset();
        }

        message = string.Format("WriteData: {0}\r\nMessageType={1}\r\n", s, MessageType.Outgoing);

        expectedLength = expectedResponseLength;

        if (!comPort.IsOpen)
            comPort.Open();


        byte[] bs = new byte[s.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
            bs[i] = (byte)s[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)       
        {
            response = string.Empty;
            comPort.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);

            if (resetEvent.WaitOne(5000))
            {
                return response;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Message failed to send.");
    }

    public virtual bool OpenPort()
    {
        try
        {
            if (comPort.IsOpen)
                comPort.Close();
            comPort.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            comPort.DtrEnable = false;
            comPort.RtsEnable = false;
            comPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
            comPort.ReadTimeout = -1;
            comPort.ReadBufferSize = 1024;
            comPort.BaudRate = int.Parse(BaudRate);
            comPort.DataBits = int.Parse(DataBits);
            comPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), StopBits);
            comPort.PortName = PortName;
            comPort.Open();
            message = string.Concat("OpenPort: ", MessageType.Normal, ", Port opened at ", DateTime.Now);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = "OpenPort: " + MessageType.Error + ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

                   string RcvByte = comPort.ReadExisting();

        // Encode the string.
                   byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(RcvByte);


        // Decode bytes back to string.            
                    RcvByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encodedBytes);
                    response += RcvByte;


        lock (messageLock)
        {
            if (response.Length >= expectedLength)
            {
                resetEvent.Set();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Encode it as Base64 before sending. It will become larger, but Base64 encoded bytes have well defined characters. You will have to decode it on the other side though, but the sending mechanism should no longer choke.

Comment: @Bertus: UTF-7 would work just as well, if you're already starting with Unicode.

Comment: The working version shows F6 mapped to ö which is the same as Unicode encoding. UTF7 will map this character to two bytes. I will look into Base64 encoding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need know what code page the other device (the one you're communicating with over the serial port) expects. It may be UTF-8 (Unicode) in theory but for an older device it is mostly likely some single byte code page. For example it may be Windows-1252 for Western European Windows code page. So depending on the other device you may need to change your `comPort.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();` in `OpenPort` to something like this:

```
comPort.Encoding = new Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

Then, as you only seem to exchange with strings (i.e. no binary data in the communication protocol), use `SerialPort.Write(String)` overload instead of `SerialPort.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`. The former will take care of code page conversion provided you've set `Encoding` property correctly. This means you need to remove all the `bs` array stuff and just invoke

```
comPort.Write(s);
```

in your `WriteData` method.

*By the way, the `bs` filling code was incorrect if non-ASCII characters could appear in the input string. You'd better use `Encoding.GetBytes` to get it: `byte[] bs = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);`*

In the `SerialPort_DataReceived` method `ReadExisting()` reads response as a `string`, which is ready to use (again, provided you've set up `Encoding` property correctly). So no need to re-convert with `GetBytes`/`GetString`, just set the `response`:

```
response += comPort.ReadExisting();
```

You also need to fix synchronization in your code. You have to wrap with `lock ...` access to the `response` variable since it's accessed for read and write from two threads. I would also tried to ensure `WriteData` is not called concurrently (not implemented in the sample below).

As a result, I suggest to rewrite your serial port reading and writing methods as follows:

```
public virtual string WriteData(string s, int expectedResponseLength)
{
    resetEvent.Reset(); // no need to lock this

    expectedLength = expectedResponseLength;

    if (!comPort.IsOpen)
        comPort.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)       
    {
        lock (messageLock)
        {
            response = string.Empty;
        }
        comPort.Write(s);
        if (resetEvent.WaitOne(5000))
            lock (messageLock)
            {
                return response;
            }
    }

    throw new Exception("Message failed to send.");
}

private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string received = comPort.ReadExisting();
    lock (messageLock)
    {
        response += received;
        if (response.Length >= expectedLength)
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

This all still may not guarantee `WriteData` returns some response instead of throwing `"Message failed to send."` exception. The device still may not provide a response of the request length within given timeout in case of protocol violation or encoding issue. You need to trace data returned by `ReadExisting()` to track down the problem.

Comment: I tried 5 different encodings today. Only code 437 ran without an exception. It would not print anything to the form though (a blank screen showed up).

Comment: I'm not able to paste the code I tried in the comment window. WriteData gets called with the exact number of bytes specified by the serial communication protocol.